# Los while dentro de métodos Setter son válidos?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public void setRun(int run) {
    if (String.valueOf(run).length() == 8) {
        this.run = run;
    } else {
        int run_2;
        while (true) {
            run_2 = entrada.nextInt();
            String rut_largo = String.valueOf(run_2);
            if (rut_largo.length() == 8) {
                this.run = run_2;
                break;
            } else if (rut_largo.length() != 8) {
                System.out.println("El rut debe tener a lo menos 8 caracteres.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y yo me pregunto, ¿esto es válido?, y si no lo es, ¿de qué forma lo podría hacer?
Esto, lo hice con el propósito de que en el main sólo coloque esto y así válidar lo que setteas con el método:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cliente cliente_1 = new Cliente();
    Customer custom = new Customer();
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    cliente_1.setRun(entrada.nextInt());
    System.out.println(cliente_1.getRun());
}
```

Comment: Por que no sería válido? Lo que veo es que no necesitas una variable `run_2`, puedes usar el parámetro para guardar el valor de `entrada.nextInt()` o incluso guardarlo directamente en `this.run`.

Comment: @Mateo No lo sé, preguntaba en caso de que faltase a algún principio de la programación orientada a objetos, pero sí, lo modifiqué como tú dijiste e incluso quedó mejor que antes, de hecho olvidé preguntarlos pero mi pregunta iba dirigida a si es válido o "moralmente correcto" tener inputs dentro de tus setters.

Comment: " ¿esto es válido?, y si no lo es, ¿de qué forma lo podría hacer? " es mas de una pregunta, por lo que actualmente esta pregunta incluye múltiples preguntas en una. Debería centrarse en un solo problema.

Comment: Que quieras escribir código limpio, tener buenas prácticas o seguir algún patrón de diseño son cosas diferentes. Así que sé claro con la pregunta.